# How to update option menu in tkinter without a button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hello so I am new to tkinter and I'm just doing some experimenting for my Computer Science coursework at school where I want to create a system where users can enter their holidays and then this will be displayed on a visual calender later.

Currently I'd just like to be able to change the number of days shown in the date option menu if certain months are selected. Like how february only has 29 days (in most cases.)

I don't know how to do this and would appreciate any help/ideas.

I've tried looking at solutions online but I can't seem to find any that work for me.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
master = Tk() #sets a variable for tkinter main variable
master.title("Enter Your Holiday") #This shows the title for the window

month31 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
month30 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"]

filename = "dates.txt"
file = open(filename,"w") #opens a file called dates.txt for writing

Mvar = StringVar(master)
Mvar.set("January") # initial value for month
Dvar = StringVar(master)
Dvar.set("1st") # initial value for date
Yvar = StringVar(master)
Yvar.set("2019") # initial value for year

s_month = month31
current = "January"

month = OptionMenu(master, Mvar, "January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
month.pack() #creates the optionmenu button for months

date = OptionMenu(master, Dvar, *s_month)
date.pack() #creates the optionmenu button for dates


year = OptionMenu(master, Yvar, "2019","2020","2021")
year.pack() #creates the optionmenu button for years
def change_dropdown(*args): #prints current selected option
    print(Mvar.get())
    current = Mvar.get
Mvar.trace('w',lambda *args: change_dropdown) #selects current chosen option, lambda is ??

if current == "January" or "March" or "May" or "July" or "August" or "October" or "December":
    s_month = month31 #attempts at changing list for the optionmenu
else:
    s_month = month30
```

I'd like to be able to update it without the need of a refresh button and nothing happens when I run my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your optionmenus aren't set up properly

something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk  #I like to avoid the wildcard import

month = StringVar()
monthList = [
             'pick a month',
             'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
             'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
             'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
            ]

def MonthSelEvent(*args):
    if month.get() =='Feb':
        pass #feb stuff here, pass is placeholder
    elif month.get()=='Jan' #extend with 'or' to include all 31 day months
        pass #31 day month stuff here, pass is placeholder
    elif month.get()=='Apr' #extend with 'or' to include all 30 day months
        pass #30 day month stuff here, pass is placeholder
    else:
        pass #covers the 'select a month' option

monthSelect = tk.OptionMenu(master, month, *monthList, command = MonthSelEvent)
month.trace("w", MonthSelEvent) #trace on the variable that is changed
#trace triggers call on "w"
month.set(monthList[0]) #set initial value of dropdown


#to update the menu values for days 
#this would go inside the 31 day month elif
date['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
for x in month31:
    date['menu'].add_command(label = x, command = tk._setit(Dvar, x))
Dvar.set(month31[0]) #set it to first/default for selection
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how do I actually change the options in my optionmenu? Like where you put the pass under the if statements.